# how to move value from input AL to a addressing register like BX ....which is of 16-bit

Tags: assembly

i stuck in this code.....i want to take an input from user and move it into an register .....but register is of 16-bit and input store in Al which is of 8-bit ... is there any way to move value from AL to register like BX ...i do this because i want to use BX in the array like array[bx].... please help me this out..

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
MSG DB 10,13,"TIC TAC TOE $"
MSG1 DB "   $"
ARR1 DB '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
MSG2 DB 10,13,"PLAYER 1 WIN $"
MSG3 DB 10,13,"PLAYER 2 WIN $"
MSG4 DB 10,13,"GAME DRAW $"
VAR DW ?
PLAYER1 EQU 'X'
PLAYER2 EQU 'O'
.CODE
MAIN PROC
    MOV AX , @DATA
    MOV DS , AX


NEXT_LINE1: 
    MOV BX , 0             ;counter
NEXT_LINE:                     ;this loop will shape the array in matrix form 
    MOV AH , 2
    MOV DL , 0AH           ; move on next line
    INT 21H
    MOV DL , 0DH
    INT 21H
    MOV CX , 3
L1:
    MOV AH , 2            ;display content of array
    MOV DL , ARR1[BX]
    INT 21H
    MOV AH , 9
    LEA DX , MSG1      ;msg to show space between characters.. like 1  2  3 ,,,, 4  5  6
    INT 21H
    INC BX
    CMP BX , 10
    JE ELSE_IF
    LOOP L1
    JMP NEXT_LINE

ELSE_IF:
    MOV BX , 0

                       ;take input from user
    MOV AH , 1
    INT 21H
    SUB AL , 1
    ADD BX , AL        ;try to save it into register like bx , si , di ...
    MOV DX , 'X'
    MOV  ARR1[BX] , DL
    JMP NEXT_LINE1  

    MOV AH , 4CH
    INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
    END MAIN
```

Comment: Possible duplication, please check the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879740/linux-nasm-move-a-value-in-al-up-to-ax

Answer (score 5):

A few options:

```
movzx bx, al     ; move with zero-extend

movsx bx, al     ; move with sign extend

xor bx, bx       ; clear bx 
mov bl, al
```

Answer (score 2):

As @michael said, there are some ways. (8086 assembly):

```
mov bl, al
mov bh, 0
```

more correct way:

```
cbw    ; sign extend al into ax (if it is negative)
mov bx, ax
```